# Can anyone help? I'm following a tutorial to make a basic blog site using Django and PostgreSQL and I can't add a database

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

I've added a 'templates' folder into the blog directory but I can't get the Django database urls to recognise it. I think I need to add my url into the settings.py file but I have no idea how I'm supposed to do that.

When I try to run the server I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/django-blog/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workspace/django-blog/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/django-blog/codestar/settings.py", line 91, in <module>
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/workspace/.pyenv_mirror/user/current/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dj_database_url/__init__.py", line 126, in parse
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No support for 'b'''. We support: cockroach, mssql, mssqlms, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql2, mysqlgis, oracle, oraclegis, pgsql, postgis, postgres, postgresql, redshift, spatialite, sqlite, timescale, timescalegis
```

I can't understand the problem.

The server was running completely fine until I added the templates folder. The folder contains an html file with a template for the blog posts which was provided by the tutorial, which also suggests that when I add:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    template_name = "post_list.html"
```

to the views.py file the server should display the post but that's when I get the error in the terminal.

I've tried to add the templates/ directory into the databases in settings but I don't know the correct format for it. I've even asked ChatGPT but even that seems to be stumped, probably because I've no idea what I'm meant to be asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the error statement provided by you, problem is with `DATABASE_URL` in .env file . To make it work ,

1. check postgress up and by running `sudo systemctl status postgresql` (linux).make sure to create a database.

```
psql
CREATE DATABASE yourdatabase;
CREATE USER youruser WITH PASSWORD 'yourpassword';
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase OWNER TO youruser;
```

2. make sure to install dependencies for postgress `psycopg2==2.9.9 , psycopg2-binary==2.9.9`
   cross check postgress configuration with settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': DATABASE_USER, 
        'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASS,
        'HOST': DATABASE_URL,  //'localhost'
        'PORT': DATABASE_PORT,  // default port '5432' 
    } 
}
```

.env file

````
DATABASE_PORT= '5432'
DATABASE_URL= 'localhost'
DATABASE_NAME = 'yourdatabase'
DATABASE_USER = 'youruser'
DATABASE_PASS = 'yourpassword' ```

It should make connection with database .
````

Comment: ask in case of any problem.